# Download scoped file using snowpark python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I have shared a secured view from one account to another account using the secured view in snowflake following the method described in [this link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/unstructured-data-sharing.html). The file (pdf) could be able to download from the target account's worksheet.

Is it possible to download using snowpark python api?

Comment: Shared data, is just data that is "shared" there are no files. Now the data can be exported to files via an COPY TO command. If snowpark allows you to export data, then the source of the data, (shared data, table, external table) should have no impact.

Comment: Thanks, Simeon.
According to the above link, the files in a stage can be shared with other accounts. Similar to the shared views that can be queried and displayed using the snowpark API, is it possible to download scoped files using the snowpark API? 
There is a method named session.file.get(...) in the snowpark API, but it doesn't support scoped URLs.
I wonder, is there any method in the snowpark for downloading files using scoped URLs?